# guizero - пространство между размещаемыми элементами

Tags: python, guizero

Пытаюсь сделать GUI интерфейс на *guizero*. Получается очень некрасиво. Там много вопросов, но вот самый первый:

Я использую *grid* размещение и помещаю 9 кнопок в решётку 3 х 3. И при этом все 9 кнопок сливаются друг с другом краями. Выглядит просто кошмарно.

Есть ли какая то возможность (не используя задание всех размеров и смещений в пикселах) указать менеджеру размещения, что бы он оставлял зазоры между  элементами ?

Добавляю краткий пример кода. Есть основное окно (app - grid) и в нём создаю две панели - левую и правую. Так вот слипаются своими краями. А я хочу, что бы между ними был зазор.

В функции *main()* :

```
app = App(title=app_title, layout="grid", width=1000, height=800)
g = gui()
g.setup_gui(app)
```

В методе *setup_gui(app)*:

```
self.l_box = Box(app, border=3, grid=[0, 1])
self.r_box = Box(app, border=3, grid=[1, 1])
```

Comment: Добавьте код, как именно вы делаете. Вообще, этот guizero подозрительно похож на tkinter, вот на tkinter я бы привел пример. P.S. и действительно, там tkinter под капотом. На tkinter делается через grid + отступы внутри ячеек с помощью padx, pady. Вероятно, что-то подобное есть и в guizero

Comment: Ну да, guizero - просто питоновская оболочка для TkInter.  Вырезку из кода сейчас добавлю.

Comment: По поводу паддинга я нашел только такое issue: https://github.com/lawsie/guizero/issues/361 , там один из участников обсуждения предлагает добавлять паддинг с помощью пустого бокса, но это костыль, ИМХО.

Comment: Возможно оффтоп: в одном из своих проектов с tkinter для упрощения размещения в сетке я использую вспомогательный класс, который упрощает в целом размещение, и позволяет передать дефолтные параметры во все вызовы grid: https://github.com/insolor/tk_grid_helper. Синтаксис возможно на любителя, но в целом мне удобнее использовать этот класс, чем вручную считать строки и колонки.